# HttpClient 4.x httpGet with cookies/session

Tags: java, cookies, curl, httpclient

I'm trying to get a page from a given URL which need to be authenticated to work.

I've succeeded to get cookies with a HttpPost on the login  url.
I get cookies like that, so it seems ok:

```
Cookie: [version: 0][name: ASP.NET_SessionId][value:wqvdz0bvroatgi45ywpsto2q][domain:xxx][path:/][expiry: null] 

Cookie: [version: 0][name: lan][value: 2057][domain:xxx][path: /][expiry: Thu Dec 13 02:08:52 CET 2012]
```

Now, when i try to get a page from a known url, i finally only get the "login" page.

I'm converting the code from PHP that works well. I've put  what i think is the equivalent each time.

```java
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.HTTP_CONTENT_CHARSET, CHARSET);

    //      curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, false);
    httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.IGNORE_COOKIES);

    //      curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS,true);
    //      curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.MAX_REDIRECTS, 10);
    //      curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);
    httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT,USER_AGENT); 
    //      curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);


    //      curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIE_FILE);
    Connexion con = new Connexion();
    CookieStore oldCookieStore = con.getCookieStore();
    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    for (Cookie c : oldCookieStore.getCookies()) {
        cookieStore.addCookie(c);
    }

    HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
    context.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, context);

    // Examine the response status
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

    // Get hold of the response entity
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    ... ( treat entity )
```

I haven't found the equivalent of those lines, i think it's inherent:

> ```
> //        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
> //        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
> //        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true)
> ```

Here are the logs, where we can see 3 attempts that finally end on the login URL:

```
DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager] Get connection for route {}->http://xxx
DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator] Connecting to xxx:80
DEBUG [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies] CookieSpec selected: ignoreCookies
DEBUG [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies] Cookie [version: 0][name: ASP.NET_SessionId][value: wqvdz0bvroatgi45ywpsto2q][domain: xxx][path: /][expiry: null] match [xxx:80/GENERAL.aspx]
DEBUG [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies] Cookie [version: 0][name: lan][value: 2057][domain: xxx][path: /][expiry: Thu Dec 13 02:08:52 CET 2012] match [xxx:80/GENERAL.aspx]
DEBUG [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache] Auth cache not set in the context
DEBUG [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestTargetAuthentication] Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
DEBUG [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication] Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient] Attempt 1 to execute request
DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] Sending request: GET /GENERAL.aspx?id=6414 HTTP/1.1
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] >> GET /GENERAL.aspx?id=6414 HTTP/1.1
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] >> Host: xxx
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] >> Connection: Keep-Alive
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] >> User-Agent: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 302 Found
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << HTTP/1.1 302 Found
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << Cache-Control: private
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << Content-Length: 229
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << Location: /Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fGENERAL.aspx%3id=6414
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << Date: Tue, 13 Nov 2012 01:08:51 GMT
DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy] Redirect requested to location '/Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fGENERAL.aspx%3id=6414'
DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient] Redirecting to 'http://xxx/Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fGENERAL.aspx%3id=6414' via {}->http://xxx
DEBUG [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies] CookieSpec selected: ignoreCookies
DEBUG [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies] Cookie [version: 0][name: ASP.NET_SessionId][value: wqvdz0bvroatgi45ywpsto2q][domain: xxx][path: /][expiry: null] match [xxx:80/Default.aspx]
DEBUG [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies] Cookie [version: 0][name: lan][value: 2057][domain: xxx][path: /][expiry: Thu Dec 13 02:08:52 CET 2012] match [xxx:80/Default.aspx]
DEBUG [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache] Auth cache not set in the context
DEBUG [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestTargetAuthentication] Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
DEBUG [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication] Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient] Attempt 2 to execute request
DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] Sending request: GET /Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fGENERAL.aspx%3id=6414 HTTP/1.1
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] >> GET /Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fGENERAL.aspx%3id=6414 HTTP/1.1
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] >> Host: xxx
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] >> Connection: Keep-Alive
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] >> User-Agent: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 302 Found
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << HTTP/1.1 302 Found
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << Cache-Control: private
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << Content-Length: 165
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << Location: /LOGIN.aspx
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << Date: Tue, 13 Nov 2012 01:08:52 GMT
DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy] Redirect requested to location '/LOGIN.aspx'
DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient] Redirecting to 'http://xxx/LOGIN.aspx' via {}->http://xxx
DEBUG [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies] CookieSpec selected: ignoreCookies
DEBUG [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies] Cookie [version: 0][name: ASP.NET_SessionId][value: wqvdz0bvroatgi45ywpsto2q][domain: xxx][path: /][expiry: null] match [xxx:80/LOGIN.aspx]
DEBUG [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies] Cookie [version: 0][name: lan][value: 2057][domain: xxx][path: /][expiry: Thu Dec 13 02:08:52 CET 2012] match [xxx:80/LOGIN.aspx]
DEBUG [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache] Auth cache not set in the context
DEBUG [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestTargetAuthentication] Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
DEBUG [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication] Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient] Attempt 3 to execute request
DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] Sending request: GET /LOGIN.aspx HTTP/1.1
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] >> GET /LOGIN.aspx HTTP/1.1
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] >> Host: xxx
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] >> Connection: Keep-Alive
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] >> User-Agent: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << Cache-Control: no-cache
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << Pragma: no-cache
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << Content-Length: 66322
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
DEBUG [org.apache.http.headers] << Date: Tue, 13 Nov 2012 01:08:52 GMT
DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager] Releasing connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl@4cf7c31d
DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code:

```
   httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.IGNORE_COOKIES);
```

is causing HttpClient to not store any cookies.

I assume that the server tracks your login via cookies, so since you're not storing any, you always appear to be unauthenticated, hence the login page.

Comment: I don't store them, but specify it in the one i want to use, aren't it the same ?
Anyway, i had already tried all COOKIE_POLICY, such as BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY, BEST_MATCH or any RFC specifications.

Comment: No, they are not the same thing.
Try commenting out the line of code that sets the cookie policy - let it default. See what you get.

Comment: I got the same result. ( By default it uses best_match ).

Comment: My suggestion - try it with just a plain, default HttpClient, without all of the other monkey-business. It's not clear to me what a 'Connexion' is, or where a new instance may have gotten the cookies that you expect to use...but try simplifying, e.g. use just a single HttpClient, with it's default CookieStore, instead of getting cookies in one client, and then transferring them to another. Once you have the simple case working, you can add the more complex case if necessary.